# How can I select app for monetize in apps.admob.com if I dont have published any app on Google play store?

Tags: android, admob, google-advertising-id

I want to add Ads on my new android app. I know that how add ads on a app. But when I https://apps.admob.com for montize app, I see option for select app for monetize. I dont have any app on Google Play Store

Question.

- 1. How can I use Admobs if I dont have published any app on Google play store?
- 2. How can I add ads on existing app on Google Play Store?

Please Guide me in deeply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know how to add ads to your app. 
Do that,
By creating Ad banner/full page id from admob. 
So after publishing your app to playstore, link your application to admob. 
That's it. 
Your app might take time to show in admob. but not more than a day.

Comment: Thanks brother HourGlass

Answer (score 0):

You can add an app to be monetized manually, check add your app manually tab in admob monetize page, like this,

[image]

Comment: Yes you can, check the the screen capture

Comment: Okay, Thanks @Omar_Hassan brother.

Comment: Please accept it as a solution, if this is sufficient